# Node.js Downloading multiples files asynchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

In trying to get a hang of node.js asynchronous coding style, I decided to write a program that would read a text file containing a bunch of URLS to download and download each file. I started out writing a function to download just one file (which works fine), but having trouble extending the logic to download multiple files.

Here's the code:

```
var http     = require("http"),
    fs       = require("fs"),
    input    = process.argv[2],
    folder   = "C:/Users/Wiz/Downloads/",
    regex    = /(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?/,
    urls     = null,
    url      = "",
    filename = "";

fs.readFile(input, "utf8", function(e, data) {
    console.log("Reading file: " + input);
    if (e) console.log("Got error:" + e.message);
    urls = data.split("\n");
    for (var i = urls.length; i--;) {
        url = urls[i];
        if (!url.match(regex)) continue;
        filename = folder + url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        downloadQueue.addItem(url, filename);
    }
});

var downloadQueue = {
    queue: [],
    addItem: function(p_sSrc, p_sDest) {
        this.queue.push({
            src: p_sSrc,
            dest: p_sDest
        });
        if (this.queue.length === 1) {
            this.getNext();
        }
    },
    getNext: function() {
        var l_oItem = this.queue[0];
        http.get(l_oItem.src, function(response) {
            console.log("Downloading: " + l_oItem.dest);
            var file = fs.createWriteStream(l_oItem.dest);
            response.on("end", function() {
                file.end();
                console.log("Download complete.");
                downloadQueue.removeItem();
            }).on("error", function(error) {
                console.log("Error: " + error.message);
                fs.unlink(l_oItem.dest);
            });
            response.pipe(file);
        });
    },
    removeItem: function() {
        this.queue.splice(0, 1);
        if (this.queue.length != 0) {
            this.getNext();
        } else {
            console.log("All items downloaded");
        }
    }
};
```

How do I structure the code so that the completion of the first download can signal the initiation of the next one. Please note that this exercise is just for learning purposes, to understand how asynchronous coding works. In practice, I'm sure there are much better tools out there to download multiple files.

Comment: What doesn't work? Seems fine on the first glance.

Comment: You do realize part of the whole asynchronous thing is that you don't have to wait until one is finished to start the other right?

Comment: Node js will send out multiple download requests then handle them as they are returned it doesn't matter if one is returned before another begins or even if they return in the same order they were requested if you handle it right.

Comment: It should work, but I'm getting an ENOENT: no such file or directory exception thrown. I do realize that the whole asynchronous thing should work but it wasn't, which is why I implemented the downloadQueue to serialize the downloads.

Answer (score 0):

Try simple at first, it look like you copy paste codes and quite don't understand what they do.

Do a simple loop, that get the url, and print something.

```
var http = require('http');

URL = require('url').parse('http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now?format=%25F%20%25T%20-%20%25N')
URL['headers'] = {'User-Agent': 'Hello World'}


// launch 20 queries asynchronously
for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    console.log('Query ' + i + ' started');
    var req = http.request(URL, function(res) {
      console.log('Query ' + i + ' status: ' + res.statusCode + ' - ' + res.statusMessage);
      res.on('data', function(content){
        console.log('Query ' + i + ' ended - ' + content);
      });
    });

    req.on('error', function(err) {
      console.log('Query ' + i + ' return error: ' + err.message);
    });

    req.end();
  })(i);
}
```

All the urls will be fetched asynchronously. You can observe that the response does not arrive in order, but are still processed correctly.

The difficulty with async is not to do the things is parallel, because you just write like a single task, and execute multiple time. It becomes complicated when you need for instance to wait for all tasks to finished before continuing. And for that, have a look at [promises](https://www.promisejs.org/)

Comment: I've written every line of code myself, so I DO understand what I'm doing, not copying and pasting from somewhere else. Just confused as to why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I started out with. Figuring that each download was invoked asynchronously, they would all be independent of each other.

```
var http     = require("http"),
    fs       = require("fs"),
    input    = process.argv[2],
    folder   = "C:/Users/Wiz/Downloads/",
    regex    = /(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?/,
    urls     = null,
    url      = "",
    filename = "";

fs.readFile(input, "utf8",
  function(e, data) {
    console.log("Reading file: " + input);
    if (e) console.log("Got error:" + e.message);
    urls = data.split("\n");
    for (var i = urls.length; i--;) {
      url = urls[i];
      if (!url.match(regex)) continue;
      filename = folder + url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      http.get(url, function(response) {
                      var file =  fs.createWriteStream(filename);
                      response.on("end", function() {
                        file.end();
                      });
                      response.pipe(file);
                    })
    }
  });
```