# node.js download multiple files asyncronously with fs writestream

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, callback, fs

after doing a first question without answer [Node.js Javascript don't download images from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60869910/node-js-javascript-dont-download-images-from-array)  (you can see my first code inside comment)I've worked around my code and searched someone else that had my same problem (finded here without answer [Node.js Downloading multiples files asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33953315/node-js-downloading-multiples-files-asynchronously) ) so I've watched that he had introduced a download queue to try to do asyncronusly callbacks but trying to let finish first to download next so I've tried to figure out what can be the problem, maybe it can that the program haven't finished first writestream before starts another one, so I've tried something like `file.on("close", function() {` if not with `"close"` at least with `"end"` but this have just blocked to try to download first file with error. so my question is what I'm missing from callbacks? why download just last file?

```
        const FILEPATH = "mypath/myfolder/" 
        const HREFSFILENAME = "urls.txt"
        var NodeHelper = require("node_helper")
        var fs = require("fs");
        var http = require('http');
        var urls;/*[] = new Array();*/
        var url = "";
        filename = "";
        var regex    = /(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?/;

module.exports = NodeHelper.create({        

      start: function() {
        fs.readFile(FILEPATH + HREFSFILENAME, "utf8", function (err,data) {
          if (err) return console.log(err);
          urls = data.split("\n")
          for (i=0; i < urls.length; i++) {
            console.log("ROW" + i + ": " + urls[i])
            url = urls[i]
            if (!url.match(regex)) continue;
            filename = FILEPATH + url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
            downloadQueue.addItem(url, filename);
          }

        /*
          for (let i=0; i < urls.length; i++) {
              var request = http.get(urls[i], function(response) {
                console.log("GET" + i)
                var filename = urls[i]
                filename = filename.substr(filename.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
                console.log("FILENAME: " + filename)
                filename = FILEPATH + filename
                var file = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
                response.on("end", function() {
                  file.end();
                });
                response.pipe(file);
              });
          }*/
        });
      },
    })
            var downloadQueue = {
                queue: [],
                addItem: function(p_sSrc, p_sDest) {
                    this.queue.push({
                        src: p_sSrc,
                        dest: p_sDest
                    });
                    if (this.queue.length === 1) {
                        this.getNext();
                    }
                },
                getNext: function() {
                    var l_oItem = this.queue[0];
                    http.get(l_oItem.src, function(response) {
                        console.log("Downloading: " + l_oItem.dest);
                        var file = fs.createWriteStream(l_oItem.dest);
                        response.on("end", function() {
                            file.end()
                            console.log("Download complete.");
                            //file.on("close", function() {
                              downloadQueue.removeItem();
                            //});
                        }).on("error", function(error) {
                            console.log("Error: " + error.message);
                            fs.unlink(l_oItem.dest);
                        });
                        response.pipe(file);
                    });
                },
                removeItem: function() {
                    this.queue.splice(0, 1);
                    if (this.queue.length != 0) {
                        this.getNext();
                    } else {
                        console.log("All items downloaded");
                    }
                }
            };
```

my LOG actually is this and as you can see it download just last image

```
    [16:45:51.266] [LOG]    ROW0: http://link1/image1.jpg
    [16:45:51.271] [LOG]    ROW1: http://link2/image2.png
    [16:45:51.271] [LOG]    ROW2: http://link3/image3.png
    [16:45:52.336] [LOG]    Downloading: myPath/myfolder/image1.jpg
[18:10:58.456] [LOG]    Download complete.
[18:10:58.459] [LOG]    Whoops! There was an uncaught exception...
[18:10:58.459] [ERROR]  { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\kenzo\myPath\myfolder\image1.jpg
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path:
   'C:\\Users\\kenzo\\mypath\\myfolder\\image1.jpg\r' }
[18:10:58.736] [LOG]    Downloading: myPath/myfolder/image2.png
[18:10:58.736] [LOG]    Download complete.
[18:10:58.737] [LOG]    Whoops! There was an uncaught exception...
']8:10:58.737] [ERROR]  { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\kenzo\myPath\myfolder\image2.png
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path:
   'C:\\Users\\kenzo\\myPath\\myfolder\\image2.png\r' }
[18:10:58.994] [LOG]    Downloading: mmyPath/myfolder/image3.png
[18:10:59.026] [LOG]    Download complete.
[18:10:59.026] [LOG]    All items downloaded
```

Comment: why noy use module aync  ?? will make your life simple

Answer (score 0):

Look like issue with `getNext` function, you always taking `queue[0]`

```
getNext: function() {
           var l_oItem = this.queue[0];
```

***You can use promised base chain, to solve async issue. Here `readFile` is representing async read operation. 
ELse use async-await to make this cleaner.***

```
// Solution 3.1: Using promise
const promiseReadFile = (name) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
        readFile('promise', name, resolve)
    })
}
const p1 = promiseReadFile(files[0])
const p2 = promiseReadFile(files[1])
const p3 = promiseReadFile(files[2])
console.time("PROMISE: TOTAL_TIME")
p1
    .then(console.log)
    .then(() => p2)
    .then(console.log)
    .then(() => p3)
    .then(console.log)
    .then(console.timeEnd.bind(null, "PROMISE: TOTAL_TIME"))
// Solution 3.2: Using promise accumulator
console.time("PROMISE-V2: TOTAL_TIME")
files
    .map(promiseReadFile)
    .reduce((chain, pr) => {
        return chain.then(() => pr)
            .then(console.log)
    }, Promise.resolve())
    .then(console.timeEnd.bind(null, "PROMISE-V2: TOTAL_TIME"))
```

More: https://gist.github.com/deepakshrma/1a899bf49ccb77d3b5be771907b32e4c